# Cucumber kotlin : IllegalStateException when launching test via Intellij

Tags: kotlin, exception, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am trying to launch a cucumber (written in kotlin) via intellij.

I have a step definition class described as followed :

[image]

When I launch the test from Intellij, I have this Exception on the "Given" method: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could resolve the return type of the lambda at BusinessEventSteps.kt:19**

[image]

When using "mvn clean install" from a command line, the test runs fine.

My environment:

- MacOS
- Coretto 11.0.11
- Intellij 2021.1.1
- Kotlin 1.4.10
- cucumber 6.10.4

Comment: Cucumber is fishing in the constant pool to determine the type of the types of the lambda. Looks like Correto has an unexpected layout. I doubt that can be fixed easily or at all. That means you have to use `cucumber-java` with Kotlin instead of `cucumber-java8`.

Comment: Well, the weird thing is that it works using mvn in command line, and it also works on a collegue's PC, which only difference I see is he is on Windows. So I'm not sure that it has anything to do with the cucumber library.

Comment: It depends on the JVM that is used. Your IDE, maven and colleague are probebly using different JVMs.

Comment: Nope unfortunately we both have the same Intellij version, coretto and maven version :/

Comment: I would try to verify that very carefully. Within IDEA you have to choice of selecting different JVMs again.

Comment: How do you explain though that it works with coretto by running the tests through "mvn test" command line ?
I guess it has to be an IDE issue but i can't find out.

Comment: The root cause depends on implementation details of the JVM. So if it works in one situation and not the other, it follows that you have a different JVM. Alternatively you've got stale caches in IDEA but I assume you already ruled that out.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have found a workaround (still don't understand why this happens though).
Check out my post edit. It seems to be an issue with the native IDEA compiler.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer.

Comment: And not a clue, why other then what I said. Cucumber Java8 depends on implementation details in the JVM. If IDEA doesn't match on those details it won't work

Comment: Yeah I knew it was definetly an Intellij issue, so I started searching around about how does Intellij builds the application and on their documentation they stand: "However, IntelliJ IDEA native builder might not correctly build the Gradle or Maven project if its build script file uses custom plugins or tasks".
This is the first time I have to customize the default intellij build mechanism.
Anyway, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4):

Found a workaround.
It seems that the issue has something to do with the native Intellij compiler. Editing the **Run/Debug Configurations** and replacing the default "Build" step by a maven goal, everything works fine.

Hope this will help others !

[image]